# Solve symmetric Sylvester equation $AX+XA=C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, sylvester-equation

Given $A$ and $C$ two real symmetric matrices, solve
$$
AX + XA = C
$$

This equation can be solved using standard algorithm solving the Sylvester equation like the Bartels–Stewart algorithm.

But since there are additional symmetry hypothesis on $A$ and $C$ (and so on $X$), is their any easier way to solve it ?

By easier I mean is there a closed form expression of the solution?

If not, what would be a fast implementation of the algorithm in terms of number of operations?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/339878/91764

Comment: *"But since there are additional symmetry hypothesis on $A$ and $C$ (and so on $X$)"*... sorry, but $X$ is not necessarily symmetric. E.g. $AX+XA=0$ when $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}$ and $X=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$. But surely, when the equation is solvable, there always exists a symmetric solution $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assume that $A$ is diagonal, $A=diag((\lambda_i)_i)$ (the complexity of the calculation of the eigen-elements is $\approx 20 n^3$).
If $X=[x_{i,j}],C=[c_{i,j}]$, then

$(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)x_{i,j}=c_{i,j}$. Thus, if

1. $\lambda_i+\lambda_j=0,c_{i,j}\not= 0$ then no solution.
2. $\lambda_i+\lambda_j=0,c_{i,j}= 0$ then $x_{î,j}$ is arbitrary.
3. $\lambda_i+\lambda_j\not= 0$ then $x_{i,j}=\dfrac{c_{i,j}}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}$.

The complexity of the previous calculation is $O(n^2)$.

The set $S$ of solutions (if there are any) is an affine space of dimension $\#\{(i,j);\lambda_i+\lambda_j=0\}$.

Note 1. if there is at least one solution $X_0$, then $X_0^T$ and $(X_0+X_0^T)/2$ are also  solutions, that is, there is always at least one symmetric solution.

Note 2. The Bartels–Stewart algorithm works only when $S$ is an empty set, that is, when there is a sole solution.